# How can I find the pixel size of a Font-Awesome icon?

Tags: icons, font-awesome

I am n the process of creating a website, where I have several font-awesome icons.  I now wish to create a ribbon background for each icon.  How can I go about finding the correct pixel size of such font-awesome icon?

Comment: The icons are vector graphics, they have no fixed size. Their size is based on the text size

Comment: Thanks for this insight.  Since posting, I have gained a further understanding of how such icons now work. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Font-Awesome v 4.7.0 (the current release), the default font size is 14 px. You can find this in font-awesome.css line 16, or, using your browser's devtools to inspect an icon placed on a website. For each x level of increased size, this goes up by ems (aka, fa-2x is 2 ems, or 28px).

Comment: Thanks for this insight.

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust your font size of the icon.